# Set a coloured text and send it to the clipboard

Tags: applescript, automator, copy-paste, color

This is probably very easy, but all the solutions I found were directed to specific applications.

At my work, we use an online system within the browser and I find myself every day setting the color of my messages using the mouse, which is very annoying. I just need to enter something like:

**[green] The file was approved. [/green]** <-- this is just for illustration purposes since this question field doesn't have colors. These tags have no effect on the system.

or

**[red] The file was denied. [/red].**

Since the system is online, I can't use direct commands to set the color the text like we would do using TextEdit or any other real editor. So I wonder if there is a way to set the color of the text via Applescript (Automator Service) and send it to the clipboard because I know the browser will paste the formatted text with the right color.

Any other workaround will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As I do not have access to the web app you are using, I really cannot test if this will work for you.*

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, with limited testing works for me as coded under **macOS High Sierra**.

**Overview:** Gets the *selected text* in **Google Chrome** and places it on the *clipboard* in the chosen color as **HTML** *data*, and pastes it back over the *selected text*.<sup>1</sup>

It uses an **Automator** *Service*, set to **Service receives selected** `text` **in** `Google Chrome`, with **[] Output replaces selected text** *left unchecked*, to which a *keyboard shortcut* was assigned in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** as: **⌃⌘C**

The **Automator** *Service* uses a **Run AppleScript** *action* with the default *code* replaced entirely with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*.

**Usage:** After selecting text in **Google Chrome** then pressing **⌃⌘C** a `choose from list` *dialog box* is shown where you can select which color to make the *selected text* on the *clipboard*. You do not need to use the mouse, just keystrokes, e.g. **G-Enter** for *green*, **O-Enter** for *orange* and **R-Enter** for *red*, or **Esc** to cancel the *action*.

At this point, if all works right, the *selected text* will have been replaced with the *colored text* from the *clipboard*.<sup>1</sup> (You will have to give it a second to let the *service* complete.)

Yes, it's a few keystrokes, but once comfortable with it I believe it will become second nature and be faster then having to reach for the mouse, etc.

The [usual caveats](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) may apply for the use of this in: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

<sup>1</sup><sub>Also note that the *text box* containing the *selected text* must allow pasting back the same HTML class data type and structure that was placed on the clipboard as given in the comments to the OP as answers to the questions I asked, otherwise this will not work as coded.</sub>

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
--  # Green HTML Color: #27ae60     '23323761653630'
--  # Orange HTML Color: #e67e22;       '23653637653232'
--  # Red HTML Color: #d35400       '23643335343030'
--  # sed command 'placeholder'     '706C616365686F6C646572'

property myBrowser : "Google Chrome"

property greenHTML : «data HTML3C6D65746120636861727365743D277574662D38273E3C7370616E207374796C653D22636F6C6F723A233030666630303B223E706C616365686F6C6465723C2F7370616E3E0A»
property orangeHTML : «data HTML3C6D65746120636861727365743D277574662D38273E3C7370616E207374796C653D22636F6C6F723A236536376532323B223E706C616365686F6C6465723C2F7370616E3E0A»
property redHTML : «data HTML3C6D65746120636861727365743D277574662D38273E3C7370616E207374796C653D22636F6C6F723A236433353430303B223E706C616365686F6C6465723C2F7370616E3E0A»

property tmpHTMLdata : "/private/tmp/tmpHTMLdata"


on run {input, parameters}
    activate me
    set selectedText to item 1 of input as text

    set chosenColor to (choose from list ¬
        {"Green", "Orange", "Red"} with title ¬
        "Color Chooser" with prompt ¬
        "Which color to make the selected text?") as text

    if (chosenColor as text) is "false" then
        return
    else if chosenColor is "Green" then
        my writeToFile(greenHTML, tmpHTMLdata, true)
    else if chosenColor is "Orange" then
        my writeToFile(orangeHTML, tmpHTMLdata, true)
    else if chosenColor is "Red" then
        my writeToFile(redHTML, tmpHTMLdata, true)
    end if

    do shell script "sed -i '' -e 's|placeholder|" & selectedText & "|' " & quoted form of tmpHTMLdata
    set the clipboard to (read tmpHTMLdata as «class HTML»)
    delay 0.25
    tell application myBrowser to activate
    delay 0.25
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
end run


on writeToFile(theData, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        set theOpenedFile to open for access POSIX file theFile with write permission
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        write theData to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        close access theOpenedFile
    on error eStr number eNum
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum ¬
            buttons {"OK"} default button 1 ¬
            with title "File I/O Error..." with icon stop
        return
    end try
end writeToFile
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and other than any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>

Comment: @Mateus Ribeiro, If this doesn't work with HTML data, I can write the _code_ for an RTF data version, just let me know.

Comment: It works perfectly over Gmail and Google Spreadsheets and it IS coloring the text for the clipboard, as I was able to paste it on TextEdit. So I will mark your answer as right, even if doesn't work for me. It can help other people. However, the Kambanize system for some reason will stay black. Maybe we should try the RTF solution.

Comment: @Mateus Ribeiro, Yes, I already have the _code_ set up but just need a `get the clipboard as «class RTF »` for the green and orange colors you want to use.

Comment: something is wrong, now any text I paste in the field becomes black, even from TextEdit or other sites. Unless I am crazy, the text was colored when I brought comments from the old application. I will have to do more tests to find out what is happening.

Comment: @Mateus Ribeiro, It might be a timing issue, there are two `delay 0.25` _commands_, you might need to add another between `do shell script ...` and `set the clipboard to ...`. Or even change the _value_ a bit.

Comment: The time is perfect, it could be even faster! But I am not being able to manually paste the colored text anymore. Also when I try to edit a red text it becomes instantly black and stays like that, even if I save the edit without doing anything. So weird.

Comment: I believe your code is doing exactly what it is meant for. I will mark your answer as right and think about a different approach. Thanks for your time, I can adapt your code for many other situations. I will also contact the support next week to ask about the comment section, maybe they can help to figure out the specifications (or limitations).

Comment: ok turns out it works from Word (and not from TextEdit). I extracted the RTF data and it is an insane big expression (76.380 characters), like pretty much everything Word does. I will adapt your code trying to use that data.

Comment: @Mateus Ribeiro, The HTML data works for me in TextEdit, LibreOffice and Pages, I don't have Word. The RTF data you had posted in a comment was only around 300 characters and it too works for me. I see no reason to have to use all of the garbage (76.380 characters) Microsoft does to do the same thing that should be able to be done in a few hundred characters.

Comment: You are right. I was able to edit your code to use the RTF expression and again it works everywhere else but the Kambanize window. It also brings the whole text from Word, which is not bad, since I always type the same thing "The file was Approved". I am waiting for the support answer.

Comment: DONE! I took the whole Word garbage to build the comments using your HTML code and it went through. Thanks for your precious help. I still don't know what info was missing, but well, it is working.

Comment: @Mateus Ribeiro, Glad you got it working and I could help!